# Replacing the global variables, how and why

Tags: php, global-variables

Ok so I have worked and used my global variables until now, and it has been no problem in just calling $USER to get the user id.

Most times from people on SO and some reading here and there, it all has been so negative towards using the global var.

So now i am ready to change the way and not using global variables.

Right now i include a function, protect() which checks your session and makes the global variables such as $USER, $USERTYPE .

And then i can just use these variables as much as i want in the file.

What can replace this? I have thought of making $USER = grabUserid(); that will return the user id, and same for the user type, thats already 2 functions and i would need to make function with database queries for every variable then?

And what about my $connect, which is a PDO object for the database, handling all my queries, i would need to do $connect = connectdb(); too

And what about http requests with js to another php file, i would need to pass it, but then between there it can be unsafe (if you think of security) as you can just manipulate the user id between there..

Or maybe theres a third solution of doing this? Or should i just stick to the globals? And once and for all please mention why globals vars are so bad? is it security? or the look of dirty coding?

Comment: You need to start reading other peoples' code. Choose some open source projects that were started recently (past few years only) and read the code. Poke around Github.

Comment: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: @Dan Grossman I can only find APIs and frameworks projects in there maybe im looking wrong

Comment: There are all kinds of projects there, but there's nothing wrong with reading the code to a framework.

Comment: @Dan - I'm not too sure that this question is not a good fit. It's asking about standard practices - the why and the how. Perhaps with some grammar and question editing?

Comment: @Matt That's a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. SO questions are specific programming problems with a single correct answer. If it doesn't include code, it's probably off topic here.

Comment: Fair point. Is there a mechanism to port questions in that way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this question is really two questions: why would I stop using global vars, and how should I implement similar functionality with another construct.

**First, why you might want to stop using global vars:**
Let me say that not using global variables is not a rule so much as a guideline. While there are zealots on both sides of the issue, there are some good reasons for and against it (though I've heard more against than for). Some reasons you might want to avoid global variables:

1. Access control
   This is probably the biggest and most solid reason for not using globals. With the global variable construct, any code can use the data stored in the variable any way it wants regardless of scope or reason. Access rules can be broken and the data can be invalidated by a reckless write. Unverified access means untrustworthy data.
2. Concurrency
   If you have a global variable, which by definition have no explicit access rules, concurrency can be a real issue. If two concurrently running instances or functions are accessing that same data, there is no way to guarantee the order in which reads or writes happen - further polluting your data.
3. Coupling/Structure/Code Clarity
   Simply put, when you're using global vars in OOPHP, it's likely you're coding your way around passing your data in a more direct way. Writing with globals implies tight coupling between the procedures using that data, as well as makes it difficult to understand the data flow.  Refactoring is almost a necessity in most cases.

**Second, how you can avoid global vars:**

1. Static Vars/Objects
   One of the best ways to avoid globals is to wrap your "global" data in a static object. This allows you the minimum level of code safety of creating getters and setters around the data that can either bound check, access restrict, or at the least data lock your global variables as necessary. It may be a bit extra coding, but the level of data security you gain is worth it.
2. Refactor
   Think about the reason you're using your global data. Are you just trying to get around passing that data between functions? Are you trying to create persistent data that could be just as easily (and more effectively) be handled by $Session ? Often globals are stopgaps for quick and easy configurations or session work. Using config files or sessions add a level of functionality, extensibility, and security that is often worth the extra work.

There are a few cases where globals can be useful. In *very* small programs, where data security is entirely irrelevant, or where your data is TRULY used throughout the code with no good clear way of passing it or avoiding scope issues, it may be alright to use global vars, but in general they're bad practice.

A good way to think about it is "what would happen to my script if my global data turned out to be garbage." If the answer is anything but "not much, really," then you should probably find a way to protect that data or to rethink the way you're using it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I now can see the downhills of using globals. really. Some of my global vars is actually session vars, e.g $USER = $_SESSION['user_id']. So actually i could just remove that one and then have the $session(userid).. But then I have all my pdo queries, that runs with my pdo object $connect. And inside many of my functions where i need to work with the db I have global $connect at the top. So what should i pass the $connect around to all functions? Or can i make a function/object to handle all my queries so inside its only there it grabs

Comment: the $connect. (?sounds tricky for me while thinking and writing this). I am ready to modify all my code, if i just get to know way to do it. I have learned object and classes but I never have taken it with me and used only 1-2 times in my project. I just dont know when its time to use objects/classes.. so i use mostly functions

Comment: when you say you have global $connect do you really mean global - as in using the keyword? I can't see why your pdo object would be global. This sounds like a different question about scope.

Comment: yes global as in `global $connect` in code.. Inside a function I would need to write this, in order to make the $connect->prepare(), work, else I receive undefined function name.

Comment: Karem, I can't think of a reason why you would create a PDO connection _inside_ of a function and then try to use that same connection _outside_ of that function.  I think there's more going on in your code than the use of globals. I would look at really understanding scope and the use of PDO. This is a larger topic than is appropriate to discuss in these comments or in the context of the specific question you asked. Good luck!

Comment: Ok I will accept your answer and look back to these advices when I need them. I will create question about specially this. Thanks for your patience and help

Comment: I guess Karem has a global variable `$connect` created somewhere not inside a function. To be able to use this variable inside a function, he uses `global $connect` to "import" the variable into the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to utilize sessions, and session variables.

Sessions allow php to create a unique identifier for each current user. By being to identify each individual user, php can create variables that are specific to this session.

For example, you will probably create session variables like $Session["memberID"], $Session["last_page_visited"], etc... The beauty part about this is that each Session can only access their variables, and nobody elses.

Also, session themselves will timeout after a set period of time. This will cleanup all variables that are associated with this session. This is why using global variables is a bit bad.

1. Global variables allow for unexpected results. You do not know WHERE the variable is coming from, or who has touched it last.
2. There is a global scope, so security is an issue
3. Memory usage. If you use global variables to store a lot of information, because there is no scope that data will stick around for a very long time. I'm not sure when global variables are cleaned up (if ever).

Comment: how will this do on my pdo object $connect that is not global now, then?