# Global variables not working in PHP CLI

Tags: php

Running into a problem where my code works fine when its run with apache but when I run it through CLI it can't see this variable $jobID. Any thoughts?

PS. please dont school me on not using global variables.

EDIT:

This doesnt work:

```
$jobID = mysql_insert_id();

function someFunction() {
     global $jobID;
     echo $jobID;
}
```

This does:

```
$jobID = mysql_insert_id();

function someFunction($jobID) {
     echo $jobID;
}
```

**FIXED**
Using Register Globals:This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: From that code fragment by itself it's impossible to tell what might be wrong. Globals behave the same on the CLI and elsewhere though.

Comment: What does your code do? What do you think it should do?

Comment: It adds a line to Database, put simply when i call this function $jobID is already set so it should see it (and does with apache) but from CLI it doesnt see it. Is there an option in php.ini? Whats with the down votes?

Comment: Where is the value of that variable supposedly being set?

Comment: I don't see any statements that add a line to a Database. Your code only defines a function; it does not even call that function.

Comment: downvotes for providing no useful information in your question. it's like telling a doctor you've got a splinter in a finger, neglecting to mention that the splinter is part of an axe handle that's buried in your ribs.

Comment: I've only used this code as the simplist example rather than pasting a huge function.

Comment: @MarcB Its simple, function doesnt see variable even though I've used keyword global. The same code work fine when run by apache

Comment: no, it's not that simple. you don't tell us ANYTHING about how/where the value of this variable supposedly gets set. maybe it's `$jobID = $_POST['jobID']`, and since you're on command line, there's no POST being performed.

Comment: **Where is that variable being set?** If you don't get a value, that simply mean it's not being set, plain and simple.

Comment: $jobID = mysql_insert_id(); If I pass it through as an argument the function works, but I can't pass it through as argument when I deploy

Comment: hey!, check this stackoverflow.com/questions/764274/php-global-variable-modifier-not-working/16750299#16750299

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This maybe:

```
 $GLOBALS['jobID'] = 12; 

//Thats the way to initialize the var...and in the function:

function someFunction() {
  echo $GLOBALS['jobID'];
}

someFunction(); //testing
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: Thanks Robert this worked, any idea why global keyword doesnt work in CLI?

Comment: Not a lot....i never do an php app working on the CLI, but GLOBALS exist on any scope, because its superglobal ;)

Comment: PHP doesn't have global variables as such. It has a global scope. Variables declared outside of any functions or callbacks are implicitly held there. When the original assignment `$jobID = 12;` happens in any function/method, then it lives in a local scope (unless the `global` keyword was utilized). Which is what happened for OP, but wouldn't let on.

Answer (score 1):

PHP stores command line arguments in $argv array, rather than expands the arguments to plain variables. This expansion was bad behaviour often used by old PHP versions, so don’t use it, and use $argv array instead to access the arguments.

Comment: Its not $argv array, its a variable delared in script

Comment: I need a var and function to work on web request and CLI with function `global` the same way... why has this been coded to work differently on Web and CLI?! This makes NO sense. Where do I even see it stated the reason behind this decision by the PHP makers?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use global, pass your arguments with function calling because [[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998974/replacing-the-global-variables-how-and-why)], for example:
Change:

```
function someFunction() {
     global $jobID;
     echo $jobID;
}
```

to:

```
function someFunction($arg1) {
     echo $arg1;
}
$anyvar = 'some value';
someFunction($anyvar);
```

Comment: Its not really an option, I'm not using classes, the function has another 10 arguments and I dont want to pass $jobID as an argument for a number of reasons.